# How to check if a browser fully supports a javascript method (eg, getComputedStyle pseudo elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

My problem is specific to the getComputedStyle method. ie9 supports getComputedStyle , but doesn't support pseudo elements for getComputedStyle. Normally I would use a check like this.

```
if ( getComputedStyle ) { ... 
} else { ... stuff for ie9 }
```

However, this returns true for ie9 since it does support getComputedStyle (although it doesn't support pseudo element for it). How would I check if a browser supports this method with pseudo elements?

Comment: There's no consistent way to check whether something works across browsers.

Comment: I'd highly recommend checking out `modernizr.js` (http://modernizr.com/) to see how they do these various checks

Comment: @ExplosionPills not a very helpful or well informed response. You can check whether browsers support methods or objects.

Comment: @TucsonLabs what I meant is that there is no universal way to check every method.  You can check some specific methods, sure, but even that's not guaranteed to work across *all* browsers

Comment: @JimDeville I use modernizr, but I'm not aware of it having an ability to check for partial support of a method. Can you point to an example?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT/ADDENDUM:** Just realized you are trying to dig into the specifics of how `getComputedStyle()` on IE9 versus other browsers. So caveat if this script is not what you are looking for since it seems to simply test for the existence of `getComputedStyle()` and not specific selection options.

[This site](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?289765-getComputedStyle-not-working-in-Safari-1-3-2-0) seems to offer a solution to detecting `getComputedStyle` across browsers. Specifically this code near the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// First paramter is a nodes id, second the CSS property you want
function getCSSProperty(sNodeId, sProperty)
{
    var oNode = document.getElementById(sNodeId);

    if(document.defaultView)
    {
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oNode, null).getPropertyValue(sProperty);
    }
    else if(oNode.currentStyle)
    {
        var sProperty = sProperty.replace(/-\D/gi, function(sMatch)
        {
            return sMatch.charAt(sMatch.length - 1).toUpperCase();
        });

        return oNode.currentStyle[sProperty];
    }
    else return null;
}

alert(getCSSProperty("myDiv", "margin-bottom"));
</script>
```

**EDIT:** The original poster has a question about the regular expression logic and this is my attempt to explain. If I am wrong, please let me know or comment on what you think it is:

```
        var sProperty = sProperty.replace(/-\D/gi, function(sMatch)
        {
            return sMatch.charAt(sMatch.length - 1).toUpperCase();
        });
```

Okay, that chunk of code is doing a regular expression replace with the actual regular expression being `/-\D/gi`. Using [this guide to regular expressions](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html) (aka: regex) I think I understand it.

The `/` are delimiters; the magic happens between them. The `-` is simply matching a dash. The `\D` is a special notation that means, “matches any non-digit character”. And the `gi` is specific to the regex call and [explained here](http://www.cprenterprisesonline.com/elearning/jsref/jsref_regexp_modifier_gi.asp.htm) as: “The `gi` modifier is used to do a case insensitive search of all occurrences of a regular expression in a string.”

The nested function acts on a matches in the `replace` regex and basically does a `.toUpperCase()` on matches.

So it seems that you might be able to adapt this to match deeper functionality you are trying to detect?

Comment: Can you explain what the regular Expression is doing? It seems like if that were to work, I would only need the code within the if(oNode.currentStyle) block.

Comment: @TucsonLabs **A little clarification:** The regex there replaces all "-someword" into "Someword" in the property string. So for example "box-shadow" will become "boxShadow" and "border-left-color" will become "borderLeftColor".

Comment: No problem. Btw the reason I didn't address you in my comment was because you would already be notified. Sorry for deleting and reposting the comment. I made a mistake in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this, but if you add a specific pseudo element with CSS (or with JS), you can check to see if it exists like this:

```
if ( window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').getPropertyValue('content') === 1 ) {
// Do stuff
} else { 
// ie fall back
}
```

In this example I added an :after selector to the body tag, and added a content property from within the style sheet (the value for this property could be anything).